# ReactiveUI for Xamarin Forms: Two-way binding doesn't work for custom BindableProperty

Tags: google-maps, f#, xamarin.forms, reactiveui

I'm making an extension of the Xamarin Forms `Map` class, which is amenable to MVVM architecture. Here is the derived type:

```
type GeographicMap() =
    inherit Map()
    static let centerProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Center", typeof<GeodesicLocation>, typeof<GeographicMap>, new GeodesicLocation())
    static let radiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Radius", typeof<float>, typeof<GeographicMap>, 1.0)
    member this.Radius
        with get() = 1.0<km> * (this.GetValue(radiusProperty) :?> float)
        and set(value: float<km>) = if not <| value.Equals(this.Radius) then this.SetValue(radiusProperty, value / 1.0<km>)
    member this.Center 
        with get() = this.GetValue(centerProperty) :?> GeodesicLocation
        and set(value: GeodesicLocation) = if not <| value.Equals(this.Center) then this.SetValue(centerProperty, value)
    override this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName) =
        match propertyName with
        | "VisibleRegion" ->
            this.Center <- this.VisibleRegion.Center |> XamarinGeographic.geodesicLocation
            this.Radius <- this.VisibleRegion.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.geographicDistance
        | "Radius" | "Center" -> 
            match box this.VisibleRegion with
            | null -> this.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(this.Center |> XamarinGeographic.position, this.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.distance))
            | _ ->
                let existingCenter, existingRadius = this.VisibleRegion.Center |> XamarinGeographic.geodesicLocation, this.VisibleRegion.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.geographicDistance
                let deltaCenter, deltaRadius = Geodesic.WGS84.Distance existingCenter (this.Center), existingRadius - this.Radius
                let threshold =  0.1 * this.Radius
                if Math.Abs(deltaRadius / 1.0<km>) > threshold / 1.0<km> || Math.Abs((deltaCenter |> UnitConversion.kilometres) / 1.0<km>) > threshold / 1.0<km> then
                    this.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(this.Center |> XamarinGeographic.position, this.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.distance))
        | _ -> propertyName |> ignore
```

In my view, I have added a binding between the `Center` property and my ViewModel's `Location` property as follows:

```
type DashboardView(theme: Theme) as this = 
    inherit ContentPage<DashboardViewModel, DashboardView>(theme)
    new() = new DashboardView(Themes.AstridTheme)
    override __.CreateContent() =
        theme.GenerateGrid([|"Auto"; "*"|], [|"*"|]) |> withColumn(
            [|
                theme.VerticalLayout() |> withBlocks(
                    [|
                        theme.GenerateLabel(fun l -> this.Title <- l) 
                            |> withAlignment LayoutOptions.Center LayoutOptions.Center
                            |> withOneWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.Title @>, <@ fun (v: DashboardView) -> (v.Title: Label).Text @>)
                        theme.GenerateSearchBar(fun sb -> this.AddressSearchBar <- sb)
                            |> withSearchBarPlaceholder LocalisedStrings.SearchForAPlaceOfInterest
                            |> withTwoWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.SearchAddress @>, <@ fun (v: DashboardView) -> (v.AddressSearchBar: SearchBar).Text @>)
                            |> withSearchCommand this.ViewModel.SearchForAddress
                    |])
                theme.GenerateMap(fun m -> this.Map <- m)
                    |> withTwoWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.Location @>, <@ fun (v:DashboardView) -> (v.Map: GeographicMap).Center @>)
            |]) |> createFromColumns :> View
    member val AddressSearchBar = Unchecked.defaultof<SearchBar> with get, set
    member val Title = Unchecked.defaultof<Label> with get, set
    member val Map = Unchecked.defaultof<GeographicMap> with get, set
```

Notice that I have a two-way binding between `DashboardViewModel.Location` and `DashboardView.Map.Center`. I also have a two-way binding between `DashboardViewModel.SearchAddress` and `DashboardView.AddressSearchBar.Text`. The latter binding works; the former does not. I assume this must be because I have not set up the bindable property `GeographicMap.Center` correctly.

I know that the two-way binding isn't working because panning the map causes the `VisibleRegion` property to get modified, which in turn triggers an update of the `Center` property. However, in my ViewModel class:

```
type DashboardViewModel(?host: IScreen, ?platform: IPlatform) as this =
    inherit ReactiveViewModel()
    let host, platform = LocateIfNone host, LocateIfNone platform
    let searchResults = new ObservableCollection<GeodesicLocation>()
    let commandSubscriptions = new CompositeDisposable()
    let geocodeAddress(vm: DashboardViewModel) =
        let vm = match box vm with | null -> this | _ -> vm
        searchResults.Clear()
        async {
            let! results = platform.Geocoder.GetPositionsForAddressAsync(vm.SearchAddress) |> Async.AwaitTask
            results |> Seq.map (fun r -> new GeodesicLocation(r.Latitude * 1.0<deg>, r.Longitude * 1.0<deg>)) |> Seq.iter searchResults.Add
            match results |> Seq.tryLast with
            | Some position -> return position |> XamarinGeographic.geodesicLocation |> Some
            | None -> return None
        } |> Async.StartAsTask
    let searchForAddress = ReactiveCommand.CreateFromTask geocodeAddress
    let mutable searchAddress = String.Empty
    let mutable location = new GeodesicLocation(51.4<deg>, 0.02<deg>)
    override this.SubscribeToCommands() = searchForAddress.ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(fun res -> match res with | Some l -> this.Location <- l | None -> res |> ignore) |> commandSubscriptions.Add
    override __.UnsubscribeFromCommands() = commandSubscriptions.Clear()
    member __.Title with get() = LocalisedStrings.AppTitle
    member __.SearchForAddress with get() = searchForAddress
    member this.SearchAddress 
        with get() = searchAddress 
        // GETS HIT WHEN SEARCH TEXT CHANGES
        and set(value) = this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&searchAddress, value, "SearchAddress") |> ignore
    member this.Location 
        with get() = location 
        // DOES NOT GET HIT WHEN THE MAP GETS PANNED, TRIGGERING AN UPDATE OF ITS Center PROPERTY
        and set(value) = this.RaiseAndSetIfChanged(&location, value, "Location") |> ignore
    interface IRoutableViewModel with
        member __.HostScreen = host
        member __.UrlPathSegment = "Dashboard"
```

the `SearchAddress` setter gets hit whenever the search text is updated, while the `Location` setter does not get hit when the map is panned, causing an update of its `Center` property.

Am I missing something relating to my setup of the bindable `Center` property?

**UPDATE**: This is something to do with ReactiveUI's `WhenAnyValue` extension, which is used internally in my binding. To demonstrate this, I added a couple of lines to the View creation:

```
override __.CreateContent() =
    let result = 
        theme.GenerateGrid([|"Auto"; "*"|], [|"*"|]) |> withColumn(
            [|
                theme.VerticalLayout() |> withBlocks(
                    [|
                        theme.GenerateLabel(fun l -> this.Title <- l) 
                            |> withAlignment LayoutOptions.Center LayoutOptions.Center
                            |> withOneWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.Title @>, <@ fun (v: DashboardView) -> (v.Title: Label).Text @>)
                        theme.GenerateSearchBar(fun sb -> this.AddressSearchBar <- sb)
                            |> withSearchBarPlaceholder LocalisedStrings.SearchForAPlaceOfInterest
                            |> withTwoWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.SearchAddress @>, <@ fun (v: DashboardView) -> (v.AddressSearchBar: SearchBar).Text @>)
                            |> withSearchCommand this.ViewModel.SearchForAddress
                    |])
                theme.GenerateMap(fun m -> this.Map <- m)
                    |> withTwoWayBinding(this.ViewModel, this, <@ fun (vm: DashboardViewModel) -> vm.Location @>, <@ fun (v:DashboardView) -> (v.Map: GeographicMap).Center @>)
            |]) |> createFromColumns :> View
    this.WhenAnyValue(ExpressionConversion.toLinq <@ fun (v:DashboardView) -> (v.Map: GeographicMap).Center @>).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(fun (z) ->
        z |> ignore) |> ignore // This breakpoint doesn't get hit when the map pans.
    this.WhenAnyValue(ExpressionConversion.toLinq <@ fun (v:DashboardView) -> (v.AddressSearchBar: SearchBar).Text @>).ObserveOn(RxApp.MainThreadScheduler).Subscribe(fun (z) ->
        z |> ignore) |> ignore // This breakpoint gets hit when text is changed in the search bar.
    result
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was very simple.

I was overriding `OnPropertyChanged` without calling down to the base implementation, which fires the public `PropertyChanged` event:

```
protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (handler != null)
        handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

So what I needed to do was to add a call to `base.OnPropertyChanged()` to my override:

```
type GeographicMap() =
    inherit Map()
    static let centerProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Center", typeof<GeodesicLocation>, typeof<GeographicMap>, new GeodesicLocation())
    static let radiusProperty = BindableProperty.Create("Radius", typeof<float>, typeof<GeographicMap>, 1.0)
    member this.Radius
        with get() = 1.0<km> * (this.GetValue(radiusProperty) :?> float)
        and set(value: float<km>) = if not <| value.Equals(this.Radius) then this.SetValue(radiusProperty, value / 1.0<km>)
    member this.Center 
        with get() = this.GetValue(centerProperty) :?> GeodesicLocation
        and set(value: GeodesicLocation) = if not <| value.Equals(this.Center) then this.SetValue(centerProperty, value)
    override this.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName) =
        base.OnPropertyChanged(propertyName)
        match propertyName with
        | "VisibleRegion" ->
            this.Center <- this.VisibleRegion.Center |> XamarinGeographic.geodesicLocation
            this.Radius <- this.VisibleRegion.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.geographicDistance
        | "Radius" | "Center" -> 
            match box this.VisibleRegion with
            | null -> this.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(this.Center |> XamarinGeographic.position, this.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.distance))
            | _ ->
                let existingCenter, existingRadius = this.VisibleRegion.Center |> XamarinGeographic.geodesicLocation, this.VisibleRegion.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.geographicDistance
                let deltaCenter, deltaRadius = Geodesic.WGS84.Distance existingCenter (this.Center), existingRadius - this.Radius
                let threshold =  0.1 * this.Radius
                if Math.Abs(deltaRadius / 1.0<km>) > threshold / 1.0<km> || Math.Abs((deltaCenter |> UnitConversion.kilometres) / 1.0<km>) > threshold / 1.0<km> then
                    this.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(this.Center |> XamarinGeographic.position, this.Radius |> XamarinGeographic.distance))
        | _ -> propertyName |> ignore
```

This change allows the public event to fire. This event is translated into an `IObservable` by ReactiveUI using `Observable.FromEventPattern`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not make any other operations rather than GetValue() and SetValue() calls in your BindableProperty's get and set definitions. In order to make additional changes when this property is set or changed, you can override OnPropertyChanged method and make necessary operations there.

Comment: That's a good tip, and it's one I'll certainly implement. Even if it doesn't solve the immediate problem, it's an improvement on the existing architecture.

Comment: I made the change and edited the question accordingly. As I suspected, it hasn't fixed the issue, but it has helped clean up the code. Thanks for the suggestion.